# How to add PHP or Javascript code to a custom content type

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, drupal-7

I am working with Drupal 7.17.

I have a custom content type I created called Sidebar Ad (machine name sidebar_ad) that I want to add Javascript and PHP to. From what I understand, in the templates directory of the theme I am working with, I need to create a file called 'page--sidebar_ad.tpl.php' and I can put PHP and Javascript code in there, and it will only run in blocks and pages that contain the custom content type Sidebar Ad.

I am trying this out with one of the stock themes, Bartik, and it is not working for me. I tried it by copying the page.tpl.php file, renaming it page--sidebar_ad.tpl.php, and adding a bit of text in a few places - at the top of the php file, and in the content div. But I don't see anything change on the pages on my site that contain that custom content type.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the thing you're missing is flushing Drupal's cache...any time you add a hook or template file, you need to flush the cache so the various registries can pick it up.

In the case of an overridden page template file you also need a copy of the standard page.tpl.php file in your theme. Same goes for the node template and most likely others, you need the original in there for the overrides to work.